# Log-scale minor tick marks on outside of the axis line with annotation_logticks or alternative

Tags: r, ggplot2

annotation_logticks() is a great little function that adds minor tick marks to a log-scale axis , [as shown here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotation_logticks.html).

By default, the function draws ticks on the inside of the panel area of the plot. E.g., if on the y-axis, ticks appear on the right side of the axis line; if on the x-axis, ticks appear above the axis line.

[image: example from ggplot2 website]

I find this default undesirable for most plotting situations. Until now I have not found a simple way to get these minor ticks to display on the outside of the panel area where regular ggplot2 ticks appear. So for example on the y-axis appearing on the left side of the line instead of the right. Is there a straightforward solution to this?

For plotting situations where interpolating the values between major ticks is important it would be a very good option to have these appear on the left side where the regular ggplot2 labels and ticks normally appear. I haven't found a solution yet that does not involve clipping or abandoning annotation_logticks() altogether, and I haven;t been successful simply using a negative value for the tick mark length.

Here is the code directly from the ggplot2 website example:

```
a <- ggplot(msleep, aes(bodywt, brainwt)) +
 geom_point(na.rm = TRUE) +
 scale_x_log10(
   breaks = scales::trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
   labels = scales::trans_format("log10", scales::math_format(10^.x))
 ) +
 scale_y_log10(
   breaks = scales::trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
   labels = scales::trans_format("log10", scales::math_format(10^.x))
 ) +
 theme_bw()

a + annotation_logticks()
```

I am looking for a result that simply flips the ticks to the other side of the axis line.

Comment: check this: https://r-graphics.org/recipe-axes-axis-log-ticks (see the last figure)

Answer (score 6):

I found a tidy way to take care of this, though this solution does not have the same tick length as with `annotation_logticks()`

```
logticks <- function(datavar,type) {

  minimum <- 1/10^abs(floor(log10(min(datavar, na.rm=TRUE))))
  maximum <- 1*10^abs(floor(log10(max(datavar, na.rm=TRUE)))+1)
  multiple <- floor(log10(maximum/minimum))

  yourtickvector <- c()

  if (type=="breaks") {

    yourtickvector <- c(minimum)

    for (x in seq(0,multiple)) {

      andadd <- seq(minimum*10^x,minimum*10^(x+1),minimum*10^x)[-1]

      yourtickvector <- c(yourtickvector,andadd)

    }

  } else if (type=="labels") {

    for (x in seq(0,multiple)) {

      andadd <- c(minimum*10^x,rep("",8))

      yourtickvector <- c(yourtickvector,andadd)

    }

    yourtickvector <- c(yourtickvector,minimum*10^multiple)

  }

  return(yourtickvector)

}

# only changed the breaks / label fields below to call the above function

a <- ggplot(msleep, aes(bodywt, brainwt)) +
  geom_point(na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_x_log10(
    breaks = logticks(msleep$bodywt,"breaks"),
    labels = logticks(msleep$bodywt,"labels")
  ) +
  scale_y_log10(
    breaks = logticks(msleep$brainwt,"breaks"),
    labels = logticks(msleep$brainwt,"labels")
  ) +
  theme_bw()

a
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, yes but it's a bit gross.
TLDR::

```
b <- a + 
  # reverse ticks
  annotation_logticks(short=unit(-0.1, "cm"), mid=unit(-0.2, "cm"), long=unit(-0.3,"cm")) +
  # remove clipping
  coord_cartesian(clip="off") +
  # add space between ticks and labels
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(margin = margin(t = 10)), axis.text.y=element_text(margin = margin(r = 10)))

# get the limits of the panel in data coordinates
bb <- ggplot_build(b)$layout$panel_params[[1]]
# draw a white rectangle to cover up the additional tick marks, gross
# the coordinates are actually in powers of 10 of the data
b +
  annotation_custom(
    grob=rectGrob(gp=gpar(col=NA)),
    # the min values are -100 ie "something very large and negative"
    # the max values are the bottom-left corner of the plot plus a tiny
    #  fudge factor to cover up the stubs of the ticks (gross)
    xmin=-100, xmax=min(ab$x.range) + 0.01,
    ymax=min(ab$y.range) + 0.01, ymin=-100
  )
```

yields

[image]

You have to fudge the 0.01s and -100s in the `annotation_custom`.

---

If you look at `annotation_logticks` in the console, it has

```
layer(data = dumy_data(), # more stuff,
      geo = GeomLogticks, # lots more stuff
```

`ggplot2:::GeomLogticks` (it is not an exported function hence the triple `:::` to inspect it) shows an object with various functions to draw the ticks. Some trial and error shows that `ggplot2:::GeomLogticks$draw_panel` appears to be the function that does all the work. It looks like this function makes a dataframe with coordinates of the xstart, xend, ystart, yend of each individual tick (!).

e.g. a snippet from the body of that function

```
    if (grepl("l", sides)) {
        ticks$y_l <- with(data, segmentsGrob(y0 = unit(yticks$y, 
            "native"), y1 = unit(yticks$y, "native"), x0 = unit(yticks$start, 
            "cm"), x1 = unit(yticks$end, "cm"), gp = gpar(col = alpha(colour, 
            alpha), lty = linetype, lwd = size * .pt)))
    }
```

From this, it seems we can just provide negative lengths to `annotation_logticks`

```
a2 <- a + annotation_logticks(short=unit(-0.1, "cm"), mid=unit(-0.2, "cm"), long=unit(-0.3,"cm"))
a2
```

[image]

This doesn't really work, you can sort of see the stubs of all the tick marks if you squint hard. It looks like the tick marks are drawing correctly, **but they are being clipped by the panel area**. (If you temporarily turn off the panel border `a2 + theme(panel.border=element_rect(fill=NA, color=NA))` you can see this is the case).

To turn off clipping you can do `+ coord_cartesian(clip='off')`

```
a3 <- a2 + coord_cartesian(clip='off')
a3
```

[image]

As mentioned in `?coord_cartesian` for the `clip` argument, this can lead to "unexpected results" - the ticks are defined for a greater region than the data (I think they do full powers of 10, so if the smallest data point is half-way through a power of 10 it still calculates all the way down to the next lower power) so extend beyond the lower left corner.

A gross way to work around this is to draw a rectangle over the bottom-left part of the graph (outside the panel/in the margin) to cover up the tick marks. `annotation_custom` does this but requires coordinates in data coordinates. When using the log scale like this, the coordinates are in powers of 10, so e.g. the "10^-4" is coordinate -4.

So to draw the rectangle to cover up the extra marks, we need to have lower-left corner essentially at negative infinity (bottom left corner of the graph), and the upper-right corner at the *minimum* values on the X/Y axis.

In `annotation_custom` we want a `rectGrob` to draw a rectangle. It has a white background by default but a black border which we disable using `gpar(col=NA)`. We set the `xmin` and `ymin` coordinates to -100 (essentially something very large and negative; `-Inf` means "the lowest axis value"). We can set the `xmax` and `ymax` coordinates to the lowest axis values, which `-Inf` will do for us.

```
a3 +
   annotation_custom(
    grob=rectGrob(gp=gpar(col=NA)),
    xmin=-100, xmax=-Inf,
    ymax=-Inf, ymin=-100
  )
```

For me this doesn't quite cover up the extra tick marks, leaving annoying little dots.

[image]

Really I want the `xmax` and `ymax` to be `-Inf + a little bit` to cover up the entirety of the tick marks. But to do this we can't use `-Inf` as a shorthand for "lower limit of the axis" any more, we have to access them explicitly using

```
bb <- ggplot_build(b)$layout$panel_params[[1]]
# bb$x.range, bb$y.range
```

Then we modify the above

```
a4 <- a3 +
   annotation_custom(
    grob=rectGrob(gp=gpar(col=NA)),
    xmin=-100, xmax=min(ab$x.range) + 0.01,
    ymax=min(ab$y.range) + 0.01, ymin=-100
  )
a4
```

(I found the 0.01 by trial and error, that's not great).

This is now fine, except that the X and Y axis labels run into the ticks.
To add spacing between the labels and tick marks use

```
a5 <- a4 + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(margin = margin(t = 10)),
      axis.text.y=element_text(margin = margin(r = 10)))
a5
```

where these are margins in pixels (you can change the units, see `?margin`)

yielding the picture you saw first.
You could make it a function perhaps, allowing the user to modify the various fudge factors (the -100, + 0.01, and margin of 10 pixels).

Answer (score 1):

I realized if you want the `coord_cartesian` to work you need to set your "breaks", "limits" and "labels" in the scale command first:

```
scale_y_log10(breaks = c(0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000,100000),limits = c(0.1,100000),labels=c(0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, "100000")) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "l", outside = T, short = unit(0.05, "cm"),mid = unit(0.05, "cm"),long = unit(0.2, "cm"))+
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[ticks outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Ioi.png)